# Moving files from one network location to another

Tags: batch-file, encryption, move

I have a scenario where a user generates one/many .xml file(s) which gets created, for example, on server 1 (S1). This user does not have access to S1, and requires the file(s) to be moved - on demand - to Server 2 (S2).

Ideally I would like to achieve this via a batch file or simple application that when the user executes it, it performs the following actions:

1. Access S1 (the credentials cannot be hard coded into a script where the user can view them, they must be encrypted).
2. Move file(s) from S1 directory > S2 directory where file name starts with [string] and has a file type of .xml.
3. END

Ideally I would not like to include a date specifier so that the user can transfer any file that meets the criteria any date after the file is created. It needs to **move** them because if the files are left there the next time it is run they will be processed again.

Any advice on this would be much appreciated?

Comment: It the generation is triggered by the user, why not include the 'on demand' part into the 'generates an .xml' as an option, checkbox, parameter, whatever? Just be sure the account used to generate the xml have access to s2 to leave the file for the restricted user.

Comment: Is it possible to have S1 copy the file to S2?

Comment: @MCND Unfortunately the creation of the .xml is part of another system which cannot be modified.

Comment: @unclemeat I think I will expand my question further to cover this question.

Answer (score 0):

Without much coding/configuration, this should work

- Code the moving part in a batch file without worrying for credentials.
- Change the restricted user rights to not be able to change the batch file.
- Create a scheduled task that will be run on demand. In this task's definition is where the credentials should be configured. This task will run the batch file.
- Ensure the user have rights to run the task.
- Create a batch file or a shortcur or ... to allow the user to launch the task.

Comment: thank you for this suggestion. Would you be able to give an example of the syntax required for the batch file?

Comment: @pwl, the account configured in the scheduler as the credentials to run the task MUST have rights to access S1 and S2, so, a simple `robocopy \\s1\share\folder\from \\s2\share\folder\to *.xml` should be enough.